# How to get descendants up to a certain level in a Tree?

Tags: java, swing, tree

Which `Tree` data structure in Java allows querying for different levels of children? I have looked at `TreeNode`, `JTree`. But they dont seem to support multi level querying.

Given a `Tree`, for a specific node, I want to get the descendants up to a certain level `n`. Is there an existing implementation that I can use or should I write my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard to write a breadth-first traversal and visit all the children up to a specified level. Here is some pseudocode. Assume you have a new class:

```
public class NodeWithLevel {
    Node node;
    int level;
}
```

This class is only a wrapper used for this algorithm.
Then the "get all nodes up to level N" method would be:

```
Queue<NodeWithLevel> queue;
queue.enqueue(<0, tree.root>);    
currentLevel = 0;
while(currentLevel < N) {
    NodeWithLevel current = queue.dequeue();
    currentLevel = current.level;
    // do whatever with current
    for(Node child: current.node.children) {
       queue.enqueue(<current.level + 1, child>);
    }        
}
```

Comment: ehh ... no, why would you hard-code the level into the node? That makes it not-reusable at any other level, definitely something not fitting into Swing

Comment: Where do you see any hardcoding in the node? I'm just defining a new data type only for this algorithm, using the existing node and a level value.

Comment: hmm .. you mean you create that new one wrapping the actual node while traversing the tree, just for bookkeeping?

Comment: ahh .. okay, misunderstood that. You might consider to clarify your answer in that respect, will remove my downvote then :-)

Answer (score 1):

[DefaultMutableTreeNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) supports several traversals, using any one of them to reach your goal is left (no pun intended, it's by the api :) to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid of a complex API, the DOM might be what you need. You can query it through XPath, apply events to its nodes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that springs to mind is swing's `DefaultTreeModel` but that would still require a bit of coding on your side for the logic to get children up to a certain level.

It shouldn't be too hard to roll your own implementation.